# Memory error crippling site. Ideas for how to debug?

Tags: error, channel-images, memory-limit, memory

A client of mine just reported getting the following error when trying to edit one specific entry via the EE control panel:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 71 bytes) in [server path
>   removed]/codeigniter/system/database/DB_result.php on line 49

When I've seen memory errors on this site in the past it's been due to users trying to upload images via Channel images in safecracker that are way too large. I've identified which images belong to this entry and temporarily deleted them via FTP but that has not solved the problem.

Since I can't edit the entry on front or backend due to the memory error I don't know how to find out what's wrong with it and debug the issue?

Is anyone familiar with these memory errors and know how I could find out what's the problem?

Comment: I've contacted support for Channel Images and they say it's unlikely to be related to Channel Images at all because it uses all its memory at image upload and wouldn't be using any when you view or edit the entry. 

So looks like it's probably something else but I'm not sure what.

Comment: what FT you have in this entry? How many images in Channel Image?

Comment: @MaxLazar, lots of different field types, but as far as I can tell Channel Images is the only one that would be using a lot of memory. I think on this particular entry there's only 4 or 5 images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common Publish Page DB error for site where member can publish they entries is happens because spammers registered too many accounts. And Publish page just going down when it trying to load  the authors list. In Safecracker you don't have author list field, so it's why this issue is not effected on SC form. But you can tested it just trying to open Member list.

As temporary solution is setup

```
"Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?" = NO
```

for your default member group.

But the main action is to close your site from spammers and cleanup the exist DB.  For protection you can use add-ons like [Snaptcha](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha).

For cleanup DB from Spammers I used different queries based on what I see in DB and site specific. Most spammers can be removed by analyzing bio field.

[My queries examples](https://gist.github.com/MaxLazar/7281376#file-gistfile1-txt) - needs to be carefully with using this (and make backup first), but you can delete more then 90% spammers this way.

Comment: Thanks Max. I would have never thought to look for that!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to try:

Can you increase PHP's memory limit?

Also - since you mentioned Safecracker - is this an older site - and are you using anything other than Channel Images for your images? I've had issues with Imgsizer and switching to CE image helps.

Finally, can you either delete or turn off the entry via the db directly to get back into the cp?

Comment: PHP memory limit is already quite high. I don't think increasing it will help. There's obviously a larger issue at play here.

It's running EE 2.5.5 or something like that. Not the latest but not super old either.

Channel Images + CE Image is all I'm using for images.

The tricky thing is that it's just one entry. All other entries work fine so it's not a template issue. There must be some piece of data specific to that entry that is causing the problem.

Comment: Increasing the PHP memory limit is definitely the quick fix. Don't be afraid to bump it up pretty high, since this is just a CP issue. You might also check to make sure the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize PHP config values are also large enough.

Comment: I can get into the CP, just not edit that particular entry.

Comment: Is there an issue with an img file for that specific entry? Maybe a corrupted img, or something along those lines?

Comment: Jessica, that's what I thought it was. I deleted the images from the server that belong to that entry but it didn't fix the problem. I still think the issue must be related to a corrupt image but I may need to find away to refresh the Channel Images field after manually deleting the image files before it's solved.